# Consensus with nondeterministic chain code

Tags: evm, consensus

Ethereum Virtual Machine is necessary part of Ethereum network because it ensures deterministic code execution. For this reason, it is impossible to have chain code written in general programming languages such as c++ or rust.

Question: is it possible to ensure consensus with possibly non deterministic code?

In some easy cases of nondeterminism, the answer is yes.

For example, if the code produces 0 in 99% cases and 1 in 1% cases, then this does not present a problem for the network to reach consensus - it will deside that the code produces 0 with overwhelming probability. It does not matter that some nodes will think that it produces 1, they will be overwhelmed.

In the opposite situation, when the code produces 0 in 50% cases and 1 in another 50% cases, is also easy to deal with. We may program nodes to filter out non deterministic code and to reach consensus on deciding if the code is non deteministic. The nodes just run the code say 10 times and agree on the result. Therefore, one may be tempted to propose to mark transactions as "nondeterministic", and not guarantee liveness for them. I.e., check the code in some way, and if it fails determinism reuirement, discard it.

Nonetheless, it seems that in general it is impossible to reach consensus on determinism of the code, without actually parsing it and interpreting its semantics, as the following "theorem" illustrates ( I put quote marks because I am not 100% sure it is true, this is the reason I am asking this here).

"Theorem": It is always possible to design a set of mutually dependent transactions so that it is prohibitively costly for the nodes to reach the consensus on the determinism of this set of transactions.

Proof:

Consider the chain of transactions T(1),...,T(n) such that:

T(i+1) executes deterministacally if T(i) is included in the block

T(i+1) executes non deterministically ~50% of the time, if none of the T(1),...,T(i) is included in the block.

Then it takes A^T executions to fully determine if T(N) is deterministic, where A is the number of test runs the node runs the transaction in order to find if it is deterministic.

$\square$

So far, I do not see a way around this example. Do you see any?

Comment: What do you mean by *non deterministic* code? Having to repeat multiple times the execution doesn't seem like a good approach, when you will be satisfied? what if you hit a bug in the vm, or the cpu?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! By "nondeterministic" I mean code in general programming language like c or rust. I am trying to understand if VMs are strictly necessary for consensus. There are consensus algorithms like Avalanche that are resilient to non determinism.

Comment: The languages C and rust aren't non-deterministic, if you write a "hello world" it will always print the same. But I understand that when running in a real CPU separate runs might show differences. You have similar problem when running a distributed program. If you have one result everything is fine, but if you have two different results you aren't sure which one is the correct one.

Comment: The problem: if you allow non deterministic transactions in a block, then it is hard to reach consensus - blocks will routinely get discarded. Unless you make it difficult to submit nondeterministic code. This is possible but not easy - think de referencing unassigned pointers in c.